# Proper use of function stdout in io package

Tags: dart

What is proper usage of stdout() function from package io in dart?
I wrote such a script:

```
#import('dart:io');
void main() {
  print("Hello World");
  stdout();
}
```

and I get following output:

> firen@firen-VirtualBox:~/Downloads$ ./dart/dart-sdk/bin/dart
>   ./dart/workspace/test/text.dart Hello world Unhandled exception:
>   Object is not closure
>    0. Function: '::main' url: '/home/firen/Downloads/dart/workspace/test/text.dart' line:6 col:7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import 'dart:io';
void main() {
     String s = "Hello World";
     stdout.write(s.charCodes());
}
```

stdout is a property of type [OutputStream](http://api.dartlang.org/io/OutputStream.html) rather than method, which is why you get the "Object is not a closure" error when you try to call stdout();