# Printing the same character several times without a loop

Tags: dart, pretty-print, iterable

I would like to "beautify" the output of one of my Dart scripts, like so:

```
-----------------------------------------
OpenPGP signing notes from key `CD42FF00`
-----------------------------------------

<Paragraph>
```

And I wonder if there is a particularly simple and/or optimized way of **printing the same character `x` times in Dart**. In Python, `print "-" * x` would print the `"-"` character `x` times.

Learning from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21184758/1248449), for the purpose of this question, I wrote the following minimal code, which makes use of the core `Iterable` class:

```dart
main() {
  // Obtained with '-'.codeUnitAt(0)
  const int FILLER_CHAR = 45;

  String headerTxt;
  Iterable headerBox;

  headerTxt = 'OpenPGP signing notes from key `CD42FF00`';
  headerBox = new Iterable.generate(headerTxt.length, (e) => FILLER_CHAR);

  print(new String.fromCharCodes(headerBox));
  print(headerTxt);
  print(new String.fromCharCodes(headerBox));
  // ...
}
```

This gives the expected output, but **is there a better way** in Dart to print a character (or string) `x` times? In my example, I want to print the `"-"` character `headerTxt.length` times.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The original answer is from 2014, so there must have been some updates to the Dart language: **a simple string multiplied by an `int` works**.

```
main() {
  String title = 'Dart: Strings can be "multiplied"';
  String line = '-' * title.length
  print(line);
  print(title);
  print(line);
}
```

And this will be printed as:

```
---------------------------------
Dart: Strings can be "multiplied"
---------------------------------
```

See Dart [`String`'s multiply `*` operator docs](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-core/String/operator_multiply.html):

> Creates a new string by concatenating this string with itself a number of times.
>
> The result of `str * n` is equivalent to `str + str + ...(n times)... + str`.
>
> Returns an empty string if `times` is zero or negative.

Answer (score 13):

I use this way.

```dart
void main() {
  print(new List.filled(40, "-").join());
}
```

So, your case.

```dart
main() {
  const String FILLER = "-";

  String headerTxt;
  String headerBox;

  headerTxt = 'OpenPGP signing notes from key `CD42FF00`';
  headerBox = new List.filled(headerTxt.length, FILLER).join();

  print(headerBox);
  print(headerTxt);
  print(headerBox);
  // ...
}
```

Output:

```
-----------------------------------------
OpenPGP signing notes from key `CD42FF00`
-----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Woah, definitely more readable and elegant! I don't believe there must be a more optimized way of using plain `List`s like you did.

Comment: That was 6 years ago and the answer was given 6 years ago. What else do you want as a comment? It is need to return to the past for these years, take a new look at everything that was happening at that time, rethink everything that was then and give out a verdict that this is the wrong answer?